# download java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel from epel repo

Tags: rhel, yum, java, repository

we have redhat machine - version 7.2

we installed the epel repo as the following

```
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

 yum install epel-release


 yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id                                                                   repo name                                                                                                    status
epel/x86_64                                                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                               13,416
repolist: 13,416
```

but when we want to install the java as

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel* available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system isn't registered as is stated by the error message. The `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` comes from one of the Redhat Repos specified in the /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-repo file. Those repos don't show up when running `yum repolist` for that very reason. You won't be able to install any packages from those repos with `yum` without the system being registered.

The Java that is available from EPEL is `java-latest-openjdk` including `java-latest-openjdk-devel` which is version 1:12.0.2.9-1. You can install that one if it works but if you need 1.8.0 then you'll need to register the system with Red Hat.

Comment: as I understand epel repo can give the pkg - java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel , is it right?  , or I must to register to redhat in order to download it?

Comment: @yael No, it can't. As stated, `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` package comes from one of the Redhat Repos. The one from EPEL is `java-latest-openjdk-devel` which is 1:12.0. You need to register your system to get 1.8.0.

Comment: ok I will , I will update when I will found +1 for you

Comment: Also, since this system isn't subscribed to RHEL updates, and you claim it's running 7.2, you should expect a lot of software updates before you can even install the OpenJDK from the RHEL repositories.  The latest version of RHEL is 7.7, 7.2 came out three years ago, so I'm assuming you're around three years out of date.